# $query->set in pre_get_posts is unintentionally affecting the backend

Tags: custom-post-types, archives, pre-get-posts

So, I have a custom post type, 'properties'.

I'm using `archive-properties.php`, and need to set some parameters on the `$query`.

I don't want to use `new WP_Query` since I ran into some issues where a pagination plugin was trying to paginate the `$query` that already existed since we were on an archive page, if that makes any sense.

So now my problem is, if I set `posts_per_page` to `2` for example, and login to the backend, its only showing 2 posts.

So I need this to change the query on the frontend, but not the backend.  I don't know what to include in the if statement.

```
function set_query_parameters($query) {

    if( is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'properties' ) && !$_SESSION  ) {           
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 12);
        $query->set('orderby', array(
            'date' => 'DESC',
        ));
    }
    return $query;
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'set_query_parameters' );
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In regards to your decision not to use WP_Query, `pre_get_posts` is actually an excellent choice to make, rather than creating a new instance of WP_Query. In fact, `pre_get_posts` is exactly what you should be using when you want to change the main query. Rather than executing a separate query on each page load, it modifies the main query's parameters *before* it executes. Much more efficient!

You're almost there. **You just need to add `!is_admin()` to your `if` statement.** You also should specifically call `is_main_query()` [on the `$query` object passed to your function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query#Under_the_Hood).

With these two changes your `if` statement would now read:

```
if( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && is_post_type_archive( 'properties' ) && !$_SESSION  ) {
```

It's also worth noting that you don't need to return a value to a Wordpress action - as opposed to a *filter*. With `pre_get_posts`, the argument is [passed by reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts#Argument_is_Passed_by_Reference) so any changes you make to your `$query` variable will take effect automatically.